FSL download stuck at running glxgears
I'm trying to install FSL on windows and I'm stuck at the fourth step (https://fsl.fmrib.ox.ac.uk/fsl/fslwiki/FslInstallation/Windows) where I try running glxgears. It is running, but it has run for several hours and there doesn't seem to be any progress. What could be going wrong?

What progress??? If it runs, it works, close it, and go on with step 5.

Thank you, I figured that out too hahah...
